# Thinking sphinx search with or condition didnt find both condition data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have in db such data (ofcourse it is "light" version):

```
id | description
1  | 5W40
2  | 5W-40
```

and i try to use such thinking sphinx gem search query:

```
fields << "(@description #{params[:oiloiliness]} | #{params[:oiloiliness].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')} )"
```

params[:oiloiliness] = "5W-40"

but for some reasons as result i see only second row...
What i do wrong?

How can i search with sphinx using or operator and see in result two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure why this is happening - it's a Sphinx issue though, not Thinking Sphinx (so I've added the Sphinx tag). A work-around is to wrap both search options in double-quotes:

```
fields << %q{(@description "#{params[:oiloiliness]}" | "#{params[:oiloiliness].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')}" )}
```

Also: you may want to consider adding hyphen to your list of [ignore_chars](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-ignore-chars) via [config/thinking_sphinx.yml](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html).

Comment: If the hyphen not in charset_table, would the query would be the same as `5W 40 | 5W40` which is the same as `5W (40 | 5W40)` - ie needs 5W on its own. Adding quotes makes it `"5W 40" | 5W40` which is what is required - the second set of quotes not required.

Comment: hm... in log i see that params[:oiloiliness] isn't a value, just text params[:oiloiliness] ...... something wrong with " ' etc

Comment: @barryhunter   didn't understand you... what you mean... explain it

Comment: Read about the OR operator precedence, in http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Comment: @barryhunter also could you take a look at my first comment? in log i see that params[:oiloiliness] isn't a value, just text params[:oiloiliness] ...... something wrong with " ' etc

Comment: Sorry I can't I don't know ruby. Something wrong with variable interpolation withing quoted strings. But a quick Google found this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Alternate_quotes